# How to reset password that is generated with md5() and crypt()

Tags: php, crypt, md5sum

I was working on my project and I forget Admin users password. Here is users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES
(7, 'ikhlassons@gmail.com', '078bbb4bf0f7117fb131ec45f15b5b87', 'Ikhlas Sons'),
(10, 'wali_essa@hotmail.com', '078bbb4bf0f7117fb131ec45f15b5b87', 'essa');
```

Can anyone tell me how reset password in php that is generated with `md5()` and `cryp()`

Here's how the password is generated:

```
$hash = crypt($entered_password,"");
$hash = md5($hash);
```

Comment: Can you post code where you generate password ?

Comment: check the select query for login.. better post it then we can help

Comment: You're not going online with this, are you?

Comment: You realize you're using unsafe code and you **will** get hacked if you go online with this. Oh well, it's your website/db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$hash = crypt("passpass","");
$hash = md5("passpass");
echo $hash;
```

Or this:

```
$hash = crypt("passpass","");
echo $hash;
```

Remember your password is `passpass`. Copy the code into `users`.`password` field in mysql database. And use `passpass` as password when login.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra column named, for example, `password_reset_token`. When a user wants to recover his password, your app must generate a (long enough) random string and store it in than `password_reset_token` field.

Then you create a script that receives that token by `$_GET` (i.e.: `example.com/password-reset/?token=982dh89h2w9h92hd`), check if it exists in the Users table and, if correct, promtps a form to reset the password for that user.

You have to email that link (`example.com/password-reset/?token=982dh89h2w9h92hd`) to the user, telling him to click on it to reset his password.